# Integration of function not anywhere defined

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

Consider, as example, the following function $\mathbf{M}: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$:

\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r}) =
\begin{cases}
[0,0,1],  & \text{if $\mathbf{r} \in \Omega$ } \\
[0,0,0], & \text{if $\mathbf{r} \in (\mathbb{R}^3-\Omega)$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $\Omega$ is a domain: $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^3$. For example $\Omega$ is a sphere with radius 1 and center in the origin $[0,0,0]$.

The problem is how to evaluate the following integral:

\begin{equation}
I=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \nabla \times \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r})d\mathbf{r}.
\end{equation}

I know that:

\begin{equation}
  \nabla \times \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r}) =
\begin{cases}
[0,0,0],  & \text{if $\mathbf{r} \in \mathbb{R}^3-\Gamma$ } \\
?, & \text{if $\mathbf{r} \in \Gamma$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $\Gamma$ is the boundary of $\Omega$.

I think that the solution is $I=\int_{\Gamma} \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r})\times \mathbf{n}(\mathbf{r}) d\mathbf{r}$, where $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit outgoing norm of the surface $\Gamma$, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to show it.